# Chrome App and Extension interaction: no JavaScript file loaded in Chrome App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I've managed to create an extension that when you click on a button, loads the app. The app loads all fine, but the reference to the contentAppScript in the index.html file doesn't seem to load. I have a button in the app, that when it is clicked, should send just a simple message.

In the main.js of the app i have a listener that checks for messages of the extension (this part works fine)

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        if(request.msg == "buttonWasClickToSetEverythingAllInfoOfCards"){
            console.log("just testing it out");
      chrome.app.window.create("index.html", {

      });
    }
});
```

The index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script scr="contentAppScript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="input" type="button"></input>

  </body>
</html>
```

and then in the contentAppScript.js

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);

});

function buttonClicked(){
  console.log("we clicked the button");
}
```

But it doesn't even seem to load the contentAppScript.js. If i later on create this in the console all works fine and it registers the clicks. What am I doing wrong in this case?

Here is the manifest of the app:

```
{
  "name": "Homepage App",
  "description": "The Homepage App",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
    "background":{
      "scripts":[
        "main.js"
      ]
    }

  },
  "permissions":[
   {"fileSystem": ["write", "retainEntries", "directory"]},
   "storage", "browser", "notifications"
 ],
}
```

Comment: There's a typo: `scr` instead of `src` - consider using an IDE/plugin that checks these kind of things automatically.

Comment: I feel quite stupid now. I was searching for anything besides checking if i had written that correctly. It works of course